# What is considered strenuous activity in regards to a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, rests

The description for a long rest states:

> A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long, during which a character sleeps for at least 6 hours and performs no more than 2 hours of light activity, such as reading, talking, eating, or standing watch. **If the rest is interrupted by a period of strenuous activity - at least 1 hour of walking, fighting, casting spells, or similar adventuring activity** - the characters must begin the rest again to gain any benefit from it.

Which of the following interpretations is correct in regards to what is considered *strenuous activity*?

**a)**

- at least 1 hour of walking
- at least 1 hour of fighting
- at least 1 hour of casting spells

**b)**

- at least 1 hour of walking
- fighting
- casting a spell

Personally, I think option b) is correct, because option a) allows for silly shenanigans. For example, assuming a combat encounter lasts 10 rounds - that is, 1 minute in game time - then it would be possible to have 59 encounters and still benefit from the long rest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Our DM keeps interrupting our long rests](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98992/our-dm-keeps-interrupting-our-long-rests)

Comment: I have closed it as a duplicate because it seems like it is. Although worded very differently, that question *includes* the question "does 1 minute of fighting interrupt your long rest?" - If there is something that is still unclear after you have read that question and answers, feel free to edit this one to clarify why/how it is different and/or what didn't you understand.

Comment: Actually this one is a better link to: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/42123/43856