# Can a Paladin smite using an unarmed attack if they’re wearing Demon Armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, paladin, unarmed-combat

Since Demon Armor turns the wearer’s unarmed strikes into magic weapons can a Paladin smite with their unarmed strikes while wearing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, they can

Normally, Divine Smite can not be used with unarmed strikes, in spite of unarmed strikes counting as [melee weapon attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58158/is-an-unarmed-strike-considered-a-weapon-attack), because the hands do not count as weapons (in spite of them being listed in the weapon table). There is explicit ruling on this from Sage Advice compendium

> **Can a paladin use Divine Smite when they hit
> using an unarmed strike?** No. Divine Smite isn’t intended
> to work with unarmed strikes. Divine Smite does work with a melee weapon attack, and an unarmed strike can be used to make such an attack.
> But the text of Divine Smite also refers to the “weapon’s damage,” and an unarmed strike isn’t a weapon.

Demon Armor says

> The armor's clawed gauntlets **turn unarmed strikes with your hands into magic weapons** that deal slashing damage

So, with this armor, your hands now are weapons, and because they are weapons, Divine Smite's damage can be applied to them.

Comment: PS. Demon Armor is cursed so it cannot be taken off. Luckily, there is not even a penalty for [sleeping in armor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47136/are-there-any-penalties-for-wearing-armor-all-the-time) in 5e.

Comment: [Xanathar's adds a penalty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115407/28941), though like basically everything else in Xanathar's it's optional. That said, most of those optional rules make a lot of sense (I can't get a good night's sleep in jeans; imagine trying to sleep in full plate), and I'd expect a lot of DMs to adopt them if people were doing silly/abusive stuff like this all the time.