# Can I specifically bury myself with the Mold Earth spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

I have a [Reborn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/706719-lineages#Reborn) character, so I don’t need to breathe (thanks to the Deathless Nature trait).

Could I use the [*mold earth*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mold-earth) cantrip to bury myself if I need to to avoid attacks?

Comment: Related question: [Why is burying yourself not such a great plan?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/why-is-burying-yourself-not-such-a-great-plan) (A lot of those answers assume the player needs to breathe, but not all of them.)

Comment: Fwiw, a much more useful version of this effect is meld with stone (which of course requires a 3rd level spell slot and a stone surface which are not easy to come by)

Comment: it is worth mentioning 5ft of dirt is enough to crush a human being to death, so they have escaped combat bot have a whole new problem. they now are being crushed by around 9000lbs or material.

Answer (score 7):

You can move earth to "excavate" a hole, and presumably a second casting can pull the dirt back into the hole, so this seems like a valid use of the spell, albeit one that requires two turns (or a way to cast the spell twice in a turn) to use.

You'll need to work with your DM to determine the details of this, though. For example, it's up to the DM to decide when the local earth is 'loose' enough to be excavated, and your DM may make an unfortunate ruling that makes getting *out* of your instant grave somewhat tricky. For example, whether you can use somatic components while buried in loose soil (which could be overcome by the Subtle Spell metamagic) and whether having a face full of soil, even with darkvision, can be construed as making the whole 5-foot cube "a portion of dirt that you can see". ("You can excavate two square inches of dirt around each eye" isn't useful for getting out of the ground!)

Given the time requirements, I'm not sure how often this would be useful in combat, though it might be a good way to hide, or just a really weird sleeping habit. A sorcerer with the Quickened Spell metamagic could probably use it more effectively (though 2 sorcery points seems like a high cost for it).

If this is something you really want to do, it might be better to work with your DM to come up with a custom low-level spell that does exactly what you want -- perhaps a 1st level spell that lets you sink into loose earth, creating an impromptu grave, and then pushes you back out when the spell ends.

Comment: A quickened metamagic sorcerer could do it! But not as a reaction. I may also be miffed if my buddy just went and stuck his head in the sand.

Comment: @NautArch A head in the sand is worth two in the bush.

Comment: A wizard in my current group does precisely this, combined with _air bubble_.  However, I am not sure whether our DM realizes that _mold earth_ has a somatic opponent.

Comment: @NautArch Yeah, sure, exactly -- but on the other hand if the sorcerer is sitting there with 2 HP it might be the best tactical choice for him to just strategically withdraw from the fight.  (It's not that much different from Dimension Dooring back to the previous room or casting Invisibility and finding a nice quiet corner to cower in, just more thematically interesting.)

Comment: @Kirt air bubble wont help with 9000lbs of crushing force preventing you from expanding your lungs,

Comment: @John (1) I'm not the DM; it's not my call.  (2) Suffocation rules in PHB are only about air, there is nothing RAW about needing to move your chest to breathe, _air bubble_ spell says it "is **all the creature needs** to avoid suffocation", (3) I strongly doubt someone standing in a pile of loose earth has 9000lbs of _lateral_ force pressing on their chest, but you are welcome to demonstrate with calculations.

Comment: @Kirt you don't need lateral force to stop you from breathing, Watch the MythBusters episode on being buried alive a few feet of dirt is enough to cause a reinforced coffin to buckle and begin to crush.

Comment: @John Well, as a reminder, he's not exactly alive and doesn't need to breathe. Breathing isn't a problem here.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym good point I keep forgetting that part

Comment: @John Just skimming that [episode](https://www.google.com/search?q=mythbuster+buried+alive&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS934US934&oq=mythbuster+buried+alive&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIJCAEQABgNGIAEMgkIAhAAGA0YgAQyCAgDEAAYFhgeMgoIBBAAGIYDGIoFMgoIBRAAGIYDGIoF0gEJNjE1MWowajE1qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:02de0c0e,vid:iW0_-c_EM-Y) by visual inspection shows that the coffin was laid flat.  Again, I doubt there is nearly as much force on someone upright.

Comment: @John Fair point - I suppose the movement itself can't cause damage but you could move enough earth for the weight itself to.  I still wonder, with no earth _over_ the chest, whether the lateral forces are enough to compress.

Comment: @Kirt if it is loose earth it quickly fills in any open space, people buried up to their necks in trench collapse report that the biggest problem was they could not breath after a few breaths because soil packs and each exhale more falls into the cavity around the chest, only being able to breath again once their chest was dug out. if the earth is wet it does this almost instantly. the problem is the earth fills in around the chest and gets compacted by movement at which point you are not trying to move the dirt that fell in the hole but all the dirt in a cone going upward from your chest.