# How to keep people from talking over one another

Tags: group-dynamics, social

It’s been getting to the point that I now have 8 players, happy and playing together.

The problem is, due to lots of talking and yelling between players out of character we get approximately 1/4 of the stuff we’re supposed to get done per session done. What are some good ways to regulate them to stop yelling and talking over one another besides establishing out of combat initiative or a squirt bottle?

We are playing virtually and in-person- discord is much easier to mute/unmute.

Comment: Are they talking in or out of character?

Comment: Related, possible dupe? [How do I rein in a player who talks over my descriptions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106041/how-do-i-rein-in-a-player-who-talks-over-my-descriptions)

Comment: Also related/possible dupe: [How to deal with different levels of initiative and propensity to overtalk in a large group?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163787/how-to-deal-with-different-levels-of-initiative-and-propensity-to-overtalk-in-a)

Comment: @thom I think that's a great reference question but not a total duplicate because that question is about playing strictly in person whereas this question is also about playing online. Perhaps this question should be edited to focus on the online component given the subject overlap for playing in person, though.

Comment: @nautarch out of character

Comment: The stick of the speaker, who so ever holds this stick, if they are spoken over may wacket the offender...wait, you said virtual group

Comment: Just to check, when you say 8 characters, do you mean 8 players? Saying player when we mean character or vice versa is a pretty common mixup on here, and can make a material difference in answers, so I just want to check. (It can also make for a pretty amusing change in questioning meaning: "so all of my players were killed in our last encounter, and...")

Comment: @doppelgreener players

Comment: @Salami-tsunami Thanks! I've updated to add some details from these comments.

Comment: 8 players is a very large group. As a DM it makes it hard to make sure there is enough spotlight to go around, and players may be competing for it and for relevance. In my experience, for such a large group to work at all, you need experienced players that know their character's role and rules, and know how to keep a game moving. This is not intuitive and is a skill players develop over time. It is possible your group is just too big and the players (and DM) are unaware of the challenges this introduces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### It depends *why* people are talking over each other

You mention that the players are talking out of character.

If the chatter is, itself, not aimed toward moving the game forward (e.g., out of game jokes), then reminding people not to do that when you notice it happening can be effective.  It's fine every now and then in a smaller group, but with enough people (8 is a bunch) it can very quickly bog down a session.

If the chatter is different people all trying to do actions simultaneously, players in my group have often used chat to "queue up" an action or to have an in-game conversation with another character. As long as the DM is following the chat, the action will happen eventually, with the DM switching between people every so often so no one is left out.  Having a way to queue the action removes the need to constantly try to butt in.

If it's one person generally overpowering things, it might be worth either talking to that person about it (preferably 1:1 so they don't feel called out) or explicitly calling on people in turn to ask them what they want to do.  You probably don't need a formal initiative system as long as you can keep track of it in your head.  I haven't had this particular issue in any groups, so I'm speculating a bit with this last suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a group that used to have the same problem, I and our GM came up with a way to do this. Try any of these:

1. At the end of the session award the player who talked over other players the least 1-3 "polite points" that add some sort of in-game benefit (we used them like inspiration points in DnD). My group used this sort of plan, and it worked really well if we gave two people points.

   - We (me and the GM) had a "crazy old man on top of a mountain" tell the players that they were too loud (and that they talk too much, and that they are too tall, and that they eat too much, and really a ton of things) and that he is casting an advanced spell on them that makes them get these points. Then my GM said that if they were talking out of turn, they would not get the point. This worked pretty well, but technically it is not official rules.
2. Just tell them that you need them to stop! This is something that should already have been done, just speak up and tell them this isn't working. Admittedly, with 8 people there will probably still be unintentional problems.
3. (Assuming you are the GM) create a scenario where the players must work together. We have done this, with mixed results (it requires too much planning by the GM to be totally worth it)
4. USE CHAT! Discord RPG games are much more enjoyable if all of the players are using the chat actively, and the GM is paying attention to the chat. This tip was so helpful for us, after we started using chat, our games got si much better!

If none of the above work, sadly, It might be time to leave/end this campaign. Sometimes a group of people just can't RPG together effectively...

Comment: Sorry, the first thing is a typo. In practice, the first one worked the best, and we tried all of the others.

Comment: @doppelgreener I have edited to include some of my experiences, Is this what you are looking for? Sorry, I am new to Stack-Exchange!

Comment: I'd be curious how you introduced the polite points to the group. I'm worried it could be taken as a jab by some players if badly introduced.

Comment: About the experience, I'm not sure if it fits with the guidelines, but as a reader I'd like a bit more details. Things like how long did you try if it failed. Or what was the main effect if ot worked.

Comment: We did it in what I would consider a very smart way: We (me and the GM) had a "crazy old man on top of a mountain" tell the players that they were too loud (and that they talk too much, and that they are too tall, and that they eat too much, and really a ton of things) and that he is casting an advanced spell on them that makes them get these points. Then my GM said that if they were talking out of turn, they would not get the point. This worked pretty well, but technically it is not official rules so...