# Evil Friend Ruining Campaigns

Tags: campaign-development, problem-players

In my campaign I'm running, all of my characters are good. But there's one character who's evil. And everything he does is making it harder for me, as a GM and for the players. He kills important people, he burns down buildings, etc. He's done this twice before, in one campaign he killed the other players. Pissing everyone off and cutting the campaign short. In another one he did nothing but setback the players on their journey. And he's doing it again. I want everyone in my games to have fun but nobody is when he's playing like this. I want my players to kill him, but they aren't too good at RPing so the Lawful Good Paladin looks past his murders and such. I don't want to have to kill him and remove him from the game but it seems like the only option. What can I do to try and stop this without going to extremes as to remove him from my game?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [about] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. And take a look at these related questions and their answers: [1](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28802/4398), [2](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31818/4398), [3](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2478/4398), [4](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22476/4398). They should help give some context to your issue and maybe you can edit your question with them in mind.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your friends character Evil? or your friend? Because it sounds like both.

Comment: Here's [another question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30404/how-do-i-a-novice-gm-deal-with-a-pc-who-is-constantly-difficult) with excellent answers, and [another](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11189/how-do-you-deal-with-a-player-thats-determined-to-play-the-game-in-a-way-that-i?rq=1).

Comment: Related: [What is "my guy syndrome?"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome)

Comment: @Not a Punpkin It's both the character and the player who are prone to evil. His idea of fun in Minecraft is blowing up everyone's house.

Comment: @thatgirldm That does help quite a bit actually. I'll try to do that. I really don't want to kick him out though, because my DND group is a pretty close knit group of friends.

Comment: @Pallid I totally understand; it's hard to kick someone out. But like I said in that answer, if you don't, he'll poison the whole group until everyone gives up and leaves.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I think that my question was a duplicate of the second link from lisardggY. Sorry for posting duplicates, but from the time I was looking through the forums I didn't find an answer, this is sorta my first time on the site.

Comment: Be welcome, Pallid! You have done nothing wrong.

Comment: @Pallid Closing as a duplicate isn't meant to punish you for doing wrong, just to point you - and anyone who might find his way here in the future - towards the place where you'll get the best answer. No point in duplicating the answers, so we just link them this way.

Comment: OP did not mention Game system played, but since there is the passage "Lawful Good Paladin" in there, I am going to assume D&D. In that case, the paladin should leave the group or lose Paladin status. Paladins are FORBIDDEN from travelling with ANY group that is not exclusively made up out of Lawful Good characters. if he knows about even one of them not being of that alignment and chooses to follow the group anyways, he is breaking Paladin code of conduct, and therefore immediately loses Paladin status and is demoted to Warrior until he can make up to it in front of his / her deity.